# CS-Cart DB placeholder for OR

Tags: mysql, cs-cart

What is the CS-Cart DB placeholder for sql `OR` ? I try search on documentation already. But there is no example for `OR` so. The following code is what I am try to query!

```
$companies =  db_get_array('SELECT * FROM ?:companies WHERE categories LIKE ?l', $first_category, 'OR LIKE ?l', $middle_category, 'OR LIKE ?l', $last_category, 'OR LIKE ?l', $category_id);
```

But it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db_get_array(
    'SELECT * FROM ?:companies 
    WHERE categories LIKE ?l OR categories LIKE ?l...',
    $first,
    $second,
    ...
);
```

db_get_array(query with all placeholders, first parameter, second parameter, etc)

Remember to add %s to your parameters if you're using LIKE:
`$first = '%foo%';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc on CS-Cart placeholders: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/core/db/placeholders.html